# Pair Wise comparison on DataFrame Elements

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**How to do a Pairwise Iterate Columns to find Similarities.**

For All the Elemets from All The Colunms of one Data Frame, to be compared with all the elements from all the colunms of another Data Frame.

Eg :

df1 has two fields Name & Age

> Name , Age 
>   "Ajay Malhotra",      28 
>    "Sujata Krishanan" , 27 
>   "Madhav Shankar" , 33

df2 has two fields UserId & EmpId, eMail

> " UserID " , " Emp ID " , "Email "  
>   --------------------------------------  
>   "Ajay.Malhotra",      100, "a.malt@nothing.com" 
>   "Madhav.Shankar" , 101, "m.shankar"
>    "Sujata.Kris" , 1001,"Kris.Suja@nothing.com"

**Some Method to give a *Match Value*  can some hardCode 0.73 as example**

`def chekIfSame(leftString: String, rightString: String): Double = {
     // Some Logic ..Gives a MatchValue 
       0.73
    }`

How to take Each Colunms from df_1, and each Colunms from df2 , and pass it to chekIfSame.

Output could be a Cartesian product like this

> Name ,  UserId,  MatchValue 
>   --------------------------------------  
>  
>    "Sujata Krishanan",  Sujata.Kris,    0.85 
>  
>    "Ajay Malhotra",     Ajay.Malhotra , 0.98 
>  
>     "Ajay Malhotra",    Sujata.Kris ,   0.07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Two DataFrame nested for Each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047510/two-dataframe-nested-for-each-loop)

We wont be able to nested loop it.
But, we can Join and Pass it to a Function

```
joined = leftDf.join(rightDf)
val joinedWithScore = joined.withColumn("simlarScore", chekIfSame( joined(ltColName) , joined(rtColName)))
```

For this, we need to have it in chekIfSame as a UDF prior to the above operation.

```
def checkSimilarity = udf((left:String,right:String):Double => { 
// Logic or hard code 0..73
0.73
```

}