# Two DataFrame nested for Each Loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The `foreach` Loop nested iteration of DataFrams throws a NullPointerException:

```
def nestedDataFrame(leftDF: DataFrame, riteDF: DataFrame): Unit = {    
    val leftCols: Array[String] = leftDF.columns
    val riteCols: Array[String] = riteDF.columns

    leftCols.foreach { ltColName =>
        leftDF.select(ltColName).foreach { ltRow =>
            val leftString = ltRow.apply(0).toString();
            // Works ... But Same Kind Of Code Below
            riteCols.foreach { rtColName =>
              riteDF.select(rtColName).foreach { rtRow => //Exception
              val riteString = rtRow.apply(0).toString();
              print(leftString.equals(riteString)
            }
        }
    }

  }
```

**EXCEPTION:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:77)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:3406)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1334)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1352)

What could be going wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
leftDF.select(ltColName).foreach { ltRow =>
```

The above line brings your code inside the foreach block as a task to executor. Now with `riteDF.select(rtColName).foreach { rtRow =>`, you are trying to access the Spark session within the executor which is not allowed. The Spark session is only available on the driver end. In the `ofRow` method, it tries to access `sparkSession`,

```
val qe = sparkSession.sessionState.executePlan(logicalPlan)
```

You can't use dataset collections just like regular Java/Scala collection, you should rather use them by the apis available to accomplish tasks, for example you can join them to correlate date.

---

In this case, you can accomplish the comparison in a number of ways. You can join the 2 datasets, for example,

```
var joinedDf = leftDF.select(ltColName).join(riteDF.select(rtColName), $"ltColName" === $"rtColName", "inner")
```

Then analyze the `joinedDf`. You can even `intersect()` the two datasets.

Comment: A similar Question  with Illustration is found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044022/pair-wise-comparison-on-dataframe-elements/56080389#56080389